# Make Office Addin available in Word, Excel, PowerPoint & Outlook

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Is it possible to make an Addin available in Word, Excel, PowerPoint & Outlook through a single Manifest?

- I know it is feasible to make it available in Word, Excel, & PowerPoint. My concern is about Outlook

Comment: What is the value of the `type` attribute in the `<OfficeApp>` element at the top of the manifest? Also, does your manifest have a `<VersionOverrides>` element?

Answer (score 0):

There are no restrictions. The MSDN page states the following:

> To make your add-in run in one Office host application, use the Hosts and Host elements in the manifest. If you don't specify the Hosts element, your add-in will run in all hosts.

That means a single web add-in can be run in all Office hosts. You just need to omit the `Hosts` element in the manifest. Read more about that in the [Set the Hosts element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements#set-the-hosts-element) article.

Comment: I am aware of this Post. I have tried this workaround but Outlook complains about some xml elements missing or Invalid. I have made some tests adding, or removing some elements but no luck. That's why I asked here.

Comment: If you have any problems with Hosts element absence in the manifest file you can post at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/ .

Comment: @KonstantinosCheilakos and @Eugene. If there's a `<VersionOverrides>` in the manifest, then its `<Hosts>` is mandatory and overrides the `<Hosts>` in the parent of `<VersionOverrides>`, and there must be a child `<Host>`. Also, if there is a `<VersionOverrides>`, then Outlook cannot share a manifest with the other hosts. There must be a separate Outlook add-in with its own manifest. See [VersionOverrides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/versionoverrides).

Comment: @RickKirkham good to know! That confirms that it is possible with some if conditions.

Comment: @RickKirkham thanks a lot for your comment. This is good to know!

Answer (score 0):

moving my comment to be an answer:

If there's a `<VersionOverrides>` in the manifest, then its `<Hosts>` is mandatory and overrides the `<Hosts>` in the parent of `<VersionOverrides>`, and there must be a child . Also, if there is a `<VersionOverrides>`, then Outlook cannot share a manifest with the other hosts. There must be a separate Outlook add-in with its own manifest. See [VersionOverrides](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/versionoverrides).